# Getting "TypeError: 'datetime.date' object is not iterable" while iterating the tuple (conversion of tuple into list)

Tags: python, list

I have the following tuple called `data`

```
data  = (
    datetime.date(2015, 9, 11),
    datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 11, 12, 55, 24),
    'BB',
    'ABC',
    )
```

It consists of a `date`, a `datetime`, and two `str` elements.

While converting this `tuple` into a `list`, I'm trying to iterate it as follows:

```
ls = []
for i in data:
    ls.append(list(i))
```

I got the following error `TypeError: 'datetime.date' object is not iterable`.

Why?

Comment: why `list(i)` ?...you want to make a list of lists or what?

Comment: You don't have a tuple  you are calling list on the datetime.date, you sure you don't want `ls = list(data)` or `ls.append([i])`?

Comment: What Output You want?

Comment: while printing the tuple, the result is like that. _(datetime.date(2015, 9, 11), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 11, 12, 55, 24), 'BB', 'ABC')_

Comment: @SureshKumar, you are iterating over the tuple so i is each element in the tuple not the tuple itself

Comment: I need to convert this tuple into list

Comment: Yes  as I commented earlier `ls = list(data)`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I want to iterate each element

Comment: @SureshKumar, that is what you are doing. What do you think calling `list(datetime.date(2015, 9, 11))` is going to do?

Comment: If you, explicitly, want to iterate over each item of `data` to create `ls`, then just `ls.append(i)` otherwise `list(data)` will do the job for you without `for` loop

Comment: Please specify what your desired result is, or the answers you get may not be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You're iterating through the tuple fine, but the problem is with `list(i)` which **itself** tries to iterate through the element `i`, converting the elements to a list. What you want is:

```
ls = []
for i in data:
    ls.append(i)
```

Or if for some reason you want each element in its own list:

```
ls = []
for i in data:
    ls.append([i])
```

Answer (score 2):

When using a `for` loop in Python, each element of the thing you are iterating over gets bound to the name you use in the `for` statement.  So in your case:

```
for i in data:
```

- `i` is first bound to `datetime.date(2015, 9, 11)`
- `i` is then bound to the second element `datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 11, 55, 24)`
- `i` is then bound to the third element `'BB'`
- `i` is then bound to the fourth element `'ABC'`

So inside your `for` loop when you say:

```
    ls.append(list(i))
```

you are trying to create a list from each element -- and you can't make a list from a `date` nor `datetime`.

The easiest way to convert the type of your sequence from `tuple` to `list` is:

```
data = list(data)
```